# Getting issue in Amazon affiliate Product API to fetch products from amazon

Tags: api, product, ads, amazon-product-api, affiliate

We are using Amazon affiliate Product Advertising API to fetch products from amazon. The account & API KEY was working when we implemented at first time till 1 month but after that we tried again for further project development it stopped working and always displaying below error:

> AWS Access Key ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate.

Tried again and again. then finally we decided to create one more API KEY with same account but in this case on first attempt we again got same error.

After this we go to Amazon chat support but didn't find any specific solution. but they said

> Each account used for Product Advertising API is allowed an initial usage limit up to a maximum of 1 request per second and a cumulative daily maximum of 8640 requests per day (TPD) for the first 30-day period after your account has been approved. Following that period, your PA API usage limit will solely be based on your shipped item revenue. Your account will earn a usage limit of 1 TPD for every 5 cents or 1 TPS (up to a maximum of 10 TPS) for every $4320 of shipped item revenue generated via the use of Product Advertising API for shipments in the previous 30-day period.

But now the problem is we are in the development stage and can't generate the revenue. also there is no Testing/Sandbox environment.

Comment: Well shouldn't you ask that specific question from Amazon?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have used all your usage limit for the account. So to make new requests you'll need to generate some revenue from your account.

I would advice you to test your product with a dummy API that generates the same response as PA API.

You may get some ideas from the tests written in this library: https://github.com/utekaravinash/gopaapi5

If you need more help you can go through this article to understand how API requests work: https://www.utekar.com/amazon-product-advertising-api-5-go-client-library-gopaapi/

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of this open sourced library and it's written in Golang.*